# OR in Partition by

Tags: sql, oracle

I am identifying duplicates based on multiple columns,but I see that some records do not have all data that is my criteria for being a duplicate - like dob, age, gender. So I want to partition by dob, but if its null or doesn't match, partition by age, if its null or doesn't match, partition by gender. Is this possible?

```
SELECT ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, CreatedDate
FROM   (
  SELECT T1.ID, V1, V2, V3, V4, CreatedDate,
         COUNT(*)
           OVER ( PARTITION BY V1, V2, V3, V4 ) AS ct,
         COUNT( CASE CreatedDate WHEN DATE '2017-08-01' THEN 1 END )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY V1, V2, V3, V4 ) AS ct_date_match
  FROM   T1
         INNER JOIN T2
         ON ( T1.ID = T2.ID )
         INNER JOIN T3
         ON ( T1.ID = T3.ID )
)
WHERE  ct > 1
AND    ct_date_match > 0
```

If I modify my partition statement as below will it work?

```
(PARTITION BY V1, V2, V3, V4
(case when dob is null then age end), 
(case when age is null then gender_id end))
```

Comment: A few well chosen examples to illustrate both the type of issue you are trying to solve and the desired outcome would be **absolutely great**!

Comment: Also, questions like "if I do this or that, will it work?" should never be asked. There is exceptionally small likelihood that you could ever break anything in your database if you **try it yourself**. No reason to ask others what will happen!

Comment: I wasnt sure this logic would work, I didnt want to miss any records.

Comment: `dob` is a `DATE`?  `age` is an `INT`?  So what date-type do you expect `CASE WHEN dob IS NULL THEN age ELSE dob END` to be?  Don't mix data-types in this way...  Instead convert the `dob` to an `age` and THEN "merge" them...  `COALESCE(trunc(months_between(dob, CURRENT_DATE)/12), age)`

Comment: Your sample code and your description of the problem don't match.

Comment: V1-V4 are different columns, I want to partition by additional columns like dob, age, gender etc.

Answer (score 0):

@mathguy was right, you could have saved yourself some time if you had just tried it.

It will work, use coalesce function and make certain that all the coalesce function arguments are of the same type. Here is an example using int, varchar, date, and float:

```
drop table deleteme_tbl;
create table deleteme_tbl ( a int not null, b varchar2(5) , c date, d float(6), e varchar2(20));
insert into deleteme_tbl(a,b,c,d,e) values( 1, 'B', date '2017-12-01', 1.55, 'First Record');
insert into deleteme_tbl(a,b,c,d,e) values( 2, null, date '2017-12-02', 2.55, 'Second Record');
insert into deleteme_tbl(a,b,c,d,e) values( 3, 'B', null, 1.55, 'Third Record');
insert into deleteme_tbl(a,b,c,d,e) values( 4, 'B',null, null, 'Fourth Record');
insert into deleteme_tbl(a,b,c,d,e) values( 5, 'B', date '2017-12-01', 1.55, 'Fifth Record');
commit;

SELECT a.*
     , COUNT (*)
           OVER (PARTITION BY COALESCE (
                                  TO_CHAR (a)
                                , b
                                , TO_CHAR (c, 'YYYYMMDD')
                                , TO_CHAR (d)
                              ))
           cnt
  FROM deleteme_tbl a;
```

This results in:

```
A  B C         D   E               CNT
1  B 12/1/2017 1.6 First Record      1                                      
2    12/2/2017 2.6 Second Record     1                                      
3  B           1.6 Third Record      1                                      
4  B               Fourth Record     1                                      
5  B 12/1/2017 1.6 Fifth Record      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting different case statements just put COALESCE(dob,age,gender) in place of the DOB and it should work.Make sure to include it into the query output as well in case you want to see them and compare if its exactly what you needed